# Issues with javascript, posting to facebook API, via <php echo ?>, need to escape ' and "

Tags: php, javascript, escaping

ive been trying to fix this for a few houers, i cannot seem to do it successfully, here is my JS

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://www.myDomain.com/words/?w=<?php echo urlencode($facebookNoEscape['searchWord']) ?>',
    picture: 'http://www.myDomain.com/actions/image.php?img=<?php echo urlencode($image_word) ?>&dir=thumbs',
    name: '<?php echo $facebookNoEscape['word'] ?>',
    caption: 'Author: <?php echo $facebookNoEscape['nickname']?>',
    description: '<?php echo $facebookNoEscape['definition']?>'
};
```

NOTE: the values can contain "/ or '/ since i allow both in the insertion process, and they get escaped by mysqli_real_escape_string in the insertion process.

As you see, i echo the values which are from my MySQL DB, in to the object, now the result is this

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
description: 'Well, personal favorite in the following order.
all.js (line 27, col 15)
```

the string starts with a '

I have tried to json_encode, and that partialy works, i dont encunter the issue, but, i cannot use image links like:

```
'http://www.myDomain.com/actions/image.php?img=<?php echo urlencode($image_word) ?>&dir=thumbs'
```

which results in something like:

```
http://www.myDomain.com/actions/image.php?img="someImage"&dir=thumbs
```

notice the "someImage" brackets are not supposed to be there.

And all other echoed words are enclosed by "".

Any suggestions ?

EDIT: The output

```
 var obj = {
method: 'feed',
link: 'http://www.funkydictionary.com/words/?w=facebook%3D1',
picture: 'http://www.funkydictionary.com/actions/image.php?img=FunkyDictionary-            Facebook1-image.jpg&dir=thumbs',
name: 'Facebook',
caption: 'Author: bill',
description: 'Well, personal favorite in the following order.
1. A stalkers dream come true
2. The reason most work are never done on time.
```

last line is broken with something, and then it flows over

Comment: Can you show a sample of the problematic source that is actually output where you are injecting values into js using PHP?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to build your JS code like this. It almost always leads to errors.

Instead, you should build the array in PHP, and then output it using PHP's `json_encode()` function, like so:

```
<?php
$jsObj = array(
    'method' => 'feed',
    'link' => 'http://www.myDomain.com/words/?w='.urlencode($facebookNoEscape['searchWord']),
    'picture' => 'http://www.myDomain.com/actions/image.php?img='.urlencode($image_word).'&dir=thumbs',
    'name' => $facebookNoEscape['word'],
    'caption' => 'Author: '.$facebookNoEscape['nickname'],
    'description' => $facebookNoEscape['definition']
);
echo "var obj = ".json_encode($jsObj).';';
?>
```

This way, PHP will do all the right escaping for you to give you valid Javascript strings. This is the correct way to output all JSON or Javascript data from PHP.

Comment: +1 for JSON. Let PHP handle the escaping in a tested, JavaScript-specific manner.

Comment: I am now getting this error:
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

... time.\r\n\r\nSee what I mean with the examples."} function callback(response)

Comment: http://www.funkydictionary.com/words/?w=facebook%3D1#

Site if you wish to see the script error, cannot replicate this in a fiddle

Comment: @JohnDOe - I've added a semi-colon to the end of the json_encode line. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

If there are single quotes in what you're echoing, it will break your javascript. You'll need to use addslashes to escape your quotes:

```
description: '<?php echo addslashes($facebookNoEscape['definition']) ?>'
```